# What does "Renewable once, consecutively" presidential term limit mean?

Tags: president, germany, presidential-term

The German president limit limit is ["Renewable once, consecutively"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Germany).

Does this mean the he can only be re-elected once and only if immediately after his first term.

OR

Does it mean that he can be re-elected as many times as he can just as long as no more than two consecutive terms.

Answer (score 10):

There is no precedent for either scenario. It seems that [legal commentary](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundespr%C3%A4sident_(Deutschland)#Bundesversammlung_und_Ablauf_der_Wahl) reads this as "no more than two consecutive terms, unlimited total terms."

Answer (score 9):

The English translation of the Basic Law (a document that is for all intents and purposes an long term interim constitution) states in Section 5, Article 54, Clause 2 (emphasis mine):

> The term of office of the Federal President shall be five
>   years. Re-election for a **consecutive term** shall be permitted
>   only once.

This wording appears to state that the President of Germany can be elected to an unlimited number of terms but can not run for a third consecutive term (i.e. they must sit out for a term before being able to be elected again).

[Link to the English translation in PDF form](https://www.btg-bestellservice.de/pdf/80201000.pdf)

[English translation from the German Cabinet's website](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-en/chancellor/basic-law-470510)

Comment: I agree with this interpretation. If no article states otherwise than it should be possible for the same person to do a third term after an election gap. Incidentally this has happened in another country, US, where [Gover Cleveland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover_Cleveland) has won non-consecutive terms. I don't think this is possible nowadays (22nd amend.) but the powers of this position in a Presidential system (i.e. US) is very different from the same position on Parliamentary republics (or semi-presidential, i.e. EU).

Comment: @armatita The US has had few who tried to beat the accepted convention of two terms. but the 22nd amendment was brought in because FD Roosevelt managed 4 consecutive elections and Congress wanted to clamp down on that as hard as possible so limited all the ways a president could last >8 years.